Random intercept model equation with two-way interaction and extra control measure
I'm trying to figure out how I should express the following model in an equation.
The outcome is repeated 30 times within each individual, so 30 trials per individual of a certain measure (trials). All 30 trials belong to either of two groups (Group variable, 2 level factor). Within the 30 repeated measurements, there are 3 Conditions present (10 of each; Condition variable, 3 level factor). Now there is an additional continuous control measure (or covariate). For each individual, this covariate has 3 values, one belonging to each condition. In that case, is the following equation correct?
I therefore want to test fixed effects for Group, Condition and their interaction. As random effects I include intercepts per individual.
Y(ijk) = β0 + β1 Group(i) + β2 Condition(j) + β3 ( Group(i) × Condition(j) )+ β4 Control Measure(ij) +u(i) + ϵ(ijk)
To further clarify the data structure, I've created sample data:
​
library(nlme)    
set.seed(1234)
test_df <- data.frame(id = as.factor(c(rep(1,30), rep(2,30), rep(3,30), rep(4,30))), 
           group = as.factor(c(rep("placebo",30), rep("placebo",30), rep("medication",30), rep("medication",30))),
           condition = as.factor(rep(c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10), rep(3,10)),4)),
           measure = c(rnorm(10, rnorm(1,100,20), 20),rnorm(10, rnorm(1,110,20), 20),rnorm(10, rnorm(1,120,20), 20),
                       rnorm(10, rnorm(1,150,20), 20),rnorm(10, rnorm(1,170,20), 20),rnorm(10, rnorm(1,180,20), 20),
                       rnorm(10, rnorm(1,200,20), 20),rnorm(10, rnorm(1,190,20), 20),rnorm(10, rnorm(1,240,20), 20),
                       rnorm(10, rnorm(1,170,20), 20),rnorm(10, rnorm(1,190,20), 20),rnorm(10, rnorm(1,185,20), 20)),
           covariate = c(rep(rnorm(1,100,20), 10), rep(rnorm(1,110,20), 10), rep(rnorm(1,120,20), 10),
                         rep(rnorm(1,150,20), 10), rep(rnorm(1,170,20), 10), rep(rnorm(1,180,20), 10),
                         rep(rnorm(1,200,20), 10), rep(rnorm(1,190,20), 10), rep(rnorm(1,240,20), 10),
                         rep(rnorm(1,170,20), 10), rep(rnorm(1,190,20), 10), rep(rnorm(1,185,20), 10)))

test_lme <- lme(measure ~ group * condition + covariate,
                 data = test_df,
                 random = ~ 1 | id,
                 na.action = na.exclude, control = lmeControl(opt = "optim"),
                 method = "ML")


I can help if you clarify what the outcome is. In what you wrote, group is a fixed factor, but you call it the "outcome." You're making repeated measurements, I see that, but what are you measuring? Reaction time? It looks like you've got 10 measures per each of the 3 conditions, for your 30 measures. Then those are grouped?

@RickHass Yes, the outcome is indeed similar to a grouped reaction time outcome, where you have 10 measurements per condition and 3 conditions. Then there are individuals which are either part of one or another group. Each individual undergoes 30 measurements of the outcome. So Group is not an outcome. Is this what you mean?

Note: OP requests only random intercepts, not random slopes. I am providing both options, but the combined equation only for random intercepts.
Let's look at the hierarchical version of the model, as it will make it a little more transparent what's happening. I'm assuming here that you have trials nested in persons, but no other levels. We'll consider trial $t$ in subject $i$ (this is the Raudenbush & Bryk notation). I'm also assuming that condition is a trial-level variable and that group and your covariate are person-level variables. Finally, since condition has 3 levels, we need two dummy variables which I'll call condition 2 and 3 (with condition 1 being the comparison group: condition 2 = condition 3 = 0). Similarly, we'll use a dummy variable for group 1 (with the comparison being group 2). Note also, that in this scenario, you do not need subscript $j$ (or in your notation, $k$) because there are only 2 levels. Finally, it's a good idea to mean-center your covariate.
If you would like to have only intercepts randomly varying, then your two levels are:
Level 1 (trial level):
$y_{ti} = \pi_{0i} + \pi_{1i}condition2_{ti} + \pi_{2i}condition3_{ti} + e_{ti}$
Level 2 (person level), random intercepts only:
$\pi_{0i} = \beta_{00} + \beta_{01}group1_{i} + \beta_{02}covariate_{i} + r_{0i}$
$\pi_{1i} = \beta_{10} + \beta_{11}group1_{i}$
$\pi_{2i} = \beta_{20} + \beta_{21}group1_{i}$
For random slopes (intercepts and slopes as outcomes), two random effects are added for $\pi_{1i}$ and $\pi_{2i}$:
Level 2 (person level) random intercepts and slopes:
$\pi_{0i} = \beta_{00} + \beta_{01}group1_{i} + \beta_{02}covariate_{i} + r_{0i}$
$\pi_{1i} = \beta_{10} + \beta_{11}group1_{i} + r_{1i}$
$\pi_{2i} = \beta_{20} + \beta_{21}group1_{i} + r_{2i}$
That is, you expect condition to affect each outcome, and group to affect the mean outcome of a person as well as moderate the condition effect (interact). You're expecting the covariate only to affect the person's mean outcome. Since you only asked for random intercepts, I'll do only that combined model
Random intercepts only:
$y_{ti} = \{\beta_{00} + \beta_{01}group1_{i} + \beta_{02}covariate_{i} + r_{0i}\} + \{\beta_{10} + \beta_{11}group1_{i}\}condition2_{ti} + \{\beta_{20} + \beta_{21}group1_{i}\}condition3_{ti} + e_{ti}$
Now multiply and rearrange:
$y_{ti} = \beta_{00} + \beta_{01}group1_{i} + \beta_{02}covariate_{i} + \beta_{10}condition2_{ti} + \beta_{20}condition3_{ti} + \beta_{11}(group1_{i}\times condition2_{ti}) +   \beta_{21}(group1_{i}\times condition3_{ti}) + r_{0i} + e_{ti}$
$\beta_{00}$ is the overall intercept (the mean outcome for covariate = 0, group 2 condition 1), $\beta_{01}$ is the difference between a person's average outcome in group 1 v. group 2, $\beta_{02}$ is the covariate's effect on the average of a person's outcomes, $\beta_{10}$ is the average difference between a participant's outcome in condition 2 vs. condition 1, $\beta_{20}$ is the average difference between a participant's outcome in condition 3 vs. condition 1 (both assuming no interaction), $\beta_{11}$ is the amount by which the group effect might differ between conditions 2 and 1, and $\beta_{21}$ is the amount by which the group effect might differ between conditions 3 and 1. You then have 1 random effect at the person level (intercept) and the level-1 error.
If you want an ANOVA-type test of the condition and the interactions, you will have to do nested model comparisons, which isn't too difficult in lme4 in R, but you'll need to use full maximum likelihood estimation (ML), rather than REML. This is discussed in, for example, Snijders & Bosker

Thank you for this extensive answer. I realise I have trouble correctly expressing the structure of my model. The covariate is is indeed person specific, but is different for each of the 3 conditions. Does your assumption of the covariate being a person-level variable still hold in that case? I will adjust my question a bit to make this more clear.
Second question I have: I understand that a multifactor variable translate into a dummy variable for each level of that variable. But is it also correct to write the function summarized in one element as I did initially?

The initial post is now edited :)

I've also added the model definition in the nlme package.

Ah. The way you have it there it is fitting only random intercepts. Though you can do it that way, my answer depends on you specifying Random = ~ condition | id

Thank you again! Though, if I keep the nested intercepts only - no slopes - is my model equation/formula correct? Does including "k" as a subscript depend on this?

Also, what is the reason for needing a ML rather than REML definition? Thank you!

You don't need $k$ because you only have 2 levels: task level and person level. Random intercepts-only model will remove 2 random effects ($r_{1i}$ and $r_{2i}$ and changes the meaning of $\beta_{11}$ and $\beta_{21}$. I will make these edits shortly. Re: REML v. ML this comes from Snijders and Bosker's book and other sources suggesting that comparing models with different fixed effects is better with full ML v. REML
